# Adding statsmodels 'predict' results to a Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, linear-regression, prediction, statsmodels

It is common to want to append the results of predictions to the dataset used to make the predictions, but the statsmodels `predict` function returns (non-indexed) results of a potentially different length than the dataset on which predictions are based.

For example, if the test dataset, `test`, contains any null entries, then

```
mod_fit = sm.Logit.from_formula('Y ~ A B C', train).fit()
press = mod_fit.predict(test)
```

will produce an array that is shorter than the length of `test`, and cannot be usefully appended with

```
test['preds'] = preds
```

And since the result of `predict` is not indexed, there is no way to recover the rows to which the results should be attached.

What is the idiom for associating `predict` results to the rows from which they were generated? Is there, perhaps, a way to get `predict` to return a dataframe that preserves the indices of its argument?

Comment: Why does `predict` even work this way? Why not return a dataframe with indices that match those of the rows from which the predictions are made?

Comment: what version of statsmodels are you using?

Comment: I tried with `0.6.0.dev`, and there though you do not get a dataframe back, missing values are not dropped from predict output.

Comment: @behzad.nouri: So in `0.6.0.dev` `len(train) == len(preds)`, regardless of missing values in `train`? What is returned in `press` where there are missing values in `train`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Predict shouldn't drop any rows. Can you post a minimal working example where this happens? Preserving the pandas index is on my radar and should be fixed in master soon.

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1501

**Edit**: Nevermind. This is a known issue. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1352

Comment: Cool. As long as it's known and not some part of the philosophy that I wasn't grasping. I look forward to the update. Any thoughts on timeframe?