# Appending predicted values and residuals to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, prediction, statsmodels

It's a useful and common practice to append predicted values and residuals from running a regression onto a dataframe as distinct columns. I'm new to pandas, and I'm having trouble performing this very simple operation. I know I'm missing something obvious. There was [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580477/adding-statsmodels-predict-results-to-a-pandas-dataframe) asked about a year-and-a-half ago, but it wasn't really answered.

The dataframe currently looks something like this:

```
y               x1           x2   
880.37          3.17         23
716.20          4.76         26
974.79          4.17         73
322.80          8.70         72
1054.25         11.45        16
```

And all I'm wanting is to return a dataframe that has the predicted value and residual from y = x1 + x2 for each observation:

```
y               x1           x2       y_hat         res
880.37          3.17         23       840.27        40.10
716.20          4.76         26       752.60        -36.40
974.79          4.17         73       877.49        97.30
322.80          8.70         72       348.50        -25.70
1054.25         11.45        16       815.15        239.10
```

I've tried resolving this using statsmodels and pandas and haven't been able to solve it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a variation on Alexander's answer using the OLS model from statsmodels instead of the pandas ols model. We can use either the formula or the array/DataFrame interface to the models.

`fittedvalues` and `resid` are pandas Series with the correct index.
`predict` does not return a pandas Series.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [3.17, 4.76, 4.17, 8.70, 11.45],
                   'x2': [23, 26, 73, 72, 16],
                   'y': [880.37, 716.20, 974.79, 322.80, 1054.25]},
                   index=np.arange(10, 20, 2))

result = smf.ols('y ~ x1 + x2', df).fit()
df['yhat'] = result.fittedvalues
df['resid'] = result.resid


result2 = sm.OLS(df['y'], sm.add_constant(df[['x1', 'x2']])).fit()
df['yhat2'] = result2.fittedvalues
df['resid2'] = result2.resid

# predict doesn't return pandas series and no index is available
df['predicted'] = result.predict(df)

print(df)

       x1  x2        y        yhat       resid       yhat2      resid2  \
10   3.17  23   880.37  923.949309  -43.579309  923.949309  -43.579309   
12   4.76  26   716.20  890.732201 -174.532201  890.732201 -174.532201   
14   4.17  73   974.79  656.155079  318.634921  656.155079  318.634921   
16   8.70  72   322.80  610.510952 -287.710952  610.510952 -287.710952   
18  11.45  16  1054.25  867.062458  187.187542  867.062458  187.187542   

     predicted  
10  923.949309  
12  890.732201  
14  656.155079  
16  610.510952  
18  867.062458
```

As preview, there is an extended prediction method in the model results in statsmodels master (0.7), but the API is not yet settled:

```
>>> print(result.get_prediction().summary_frame())
          mean     mean_se  mean_ci_lower  mean_ci_upper  obs_ci_lower  \
10  923.949309  268.931939    -233.171432    2081.070051   -991.466820   
12  890.732201  211.945165     -21.194241    1802.658643   -887.328646   
14  656.155079  269.136102    -501.844105    1814.154263  -1259.791854   
16  610.510952  282.182030    -603.620329    1824.642233  -1339.874985   
18  867.062458  329.017262    -548.584564    2282.709481  -1214.750941   

    obs_ci_upper  
10   2839.365439  
12   2668.793048  
14   2572.102012  
16   2560.896890  
18   2948.875858
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a tremendous help!

Answer (score 3):

This should be self explanatory.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [3.17, 4.76, 4.17, 8.70, 11.45],
                   'x2': [23, 26, 73, 72, 16],
                   'y': [880.37, 716.20, 974.79, 322.80, 1054.25]})
model = pd.ols(y=df.y, x=df.loc[:, ['x1', 'x2']])
df['y_hat'] = model.y_fitted
df['res'] = model.resid

>>> df
      x1  x2        y       y_hat         res
0   3.17  23   880.37  923.949309  -43.579309
1   4.76  26   716.20  890.732201 -174.532201
2   4.17  73   974.79  656.155079  318.634921
3   8.70  72   322.80  610.510952 -287.710952
4  11.45  16  1054.25  867.062458  187.187542
```

Comment: This was simple and better.

Answer (score 1):

So, it's polite to form your questions such that it's easy for contributors to run your code.

```
import pandas as pd

y_col = [880.37, 716.20, 974.79, 322.80, 1054.25]
x1_col = [3.17, 4.76, 4.17, 8.70, 11.45]
x2_col = [23, 26, 73, 72, 16]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['y'] = y_col
df['x1'] = x1_col
df['x2'] = x2_col
```

Then calling `df.head()` yields:

```
         y     x1  x2
0   880.37   3.17  23
1   716.20   4.76  26
2   974.79   4.17  73
3   322.80   8.70  72
4  1054.25  11.45  16
```

Now for your question, it's fairly straightforward to add columns with calculated values, though I'm not agreeing with your sample data:

```
df['y_hat'] = df['x1'] + df['x2']
df['res'] = df['y'] - df['y_hat']
```

For me, these yield:

```
         y     x1  x2  y_hat      res
0   880.37   3.17  23  26.17   854.20
1   716.20   4.76  26  30.76   685.44
2   974.79   4.17  73  77.17   897.62
3   322.80   8.70  72  80.70   242.10
4  1054.25  11.45  16  27.45  1026.80
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: To add columns which are arithmetic combinations of existing columns you can also do `df.eval('y_hat = x1 + y1')` which is nice, especially if your DataFrame name is long

Comment: Very helpful. Will make sure to add dataframe source code in the future. Thank you!