# Return predicted values from a rolling regression grouped by id using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to calculate monthly rolling window regressions and return predicted values as a new column in the data frame. I know that Pandas has rolling regression capabilities (`pandas.ols`) that are in the process of being depreciated, so I'm interested in a solution that uses `statsmodels` or something similar.

I'd like to calculate monthly rolling regressions (12 month window, 6 month minimum) and save each month's prediction back to a new column in the original data frame. While my question is different, the closest solution I've found is in the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544805/python-pandas-how-to-run-multiple-univariate-regression-by-group). Based on that answer I've tried this (the data is below):

```
import pandas as pd 
import statsmodels.api as sm

def grp_ols_predict(df, xcols,  ycol):
    return sm.OLS(df[ycol], df[xcols]).fit().predict()
retdata['predicted_y'] = retdata.groupby('id').apply(grp_ols_predict, xcols=['constant','x1', 'x2', 'x3'], ycol='y')
```

There  are two issues unresolved at this point.
1. This code runs without errors but returns all `NaN` values for `predicted_y`.
2. The regression above is not rolling window. The syntax for this is straightforward in `pandas.ols`, but not in `statsmodels`. However, it seems that the idea is for the `pandas.ols` syntax to work in `statsmodels` at some point. The following code is rolling window, but will be depriciated in a future version and is not grouped by id:

```
model = pd.ols(y='y', x=retdata[['x1','x2','x3']], window_type='rolling', window=12, min_periods=6, intercept=True)
retdata['predicted_y'] = model.y_predict
```

My question is essentially ["appending predicted values and residuals to pandas dataframe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32101233/appending-predicted-values-and-residuals-to-pandas-dataframe) with two additional complications (1) rolling window and (2) grouping by id.

Finally, a sample of the data I'm using:

```
{'constant': {0: 1,  1: 1,  2: 1,  3: 1,  4: 1,  5: 1,  6: 1,  7: 1,  8: 1,  9: 1,  10: 1,  11: 1,  12: 1,  13: 1,  14: 1,  15: 1,  16: 1,  17: 1,  18: 1,  19: 1,  20: 1,  21: 1,  22: 1,  23: 1,  24: 1,  25: 1,  26: 1,  27: 1,  28: 1,  29: 1,  30: 1,  31: 1,  32: 1,  33: 1,  34: 1,  35: 1,  36: 1,  37: 1,  38: 1,  39: 1,  40: 1,  41: 1,  42: 1,  43: 1,  44: 1,  45: 1,  46: 1,  47: 1,  48: 1,  49: 1,  50: 1,  51: 1,  52: 1,  53: 1,  54: 1,  55: 1,  56: 1,  57: 1,  58: 1,  59: 1,  60: 1,  61: 1,  62: 1,  63: 1,  64: 1,  65: 1,  66: 1,  67: 1,  68: 1,  69: 1,  70: 1,  71: 1,  72: 1,  73: 1,  74: 1,  75: 1,  76: 1,  77: 1,  78: 1,  79: 1,  80: 1,  81: 1,  82: 1,  83: 1},
'id': {0: 11111,  1: 11111,  2: 11111,  3: 11111,  4: 11111,  5: 11111,  6: 11111,  7: 11111,  8: 11111,  9: 11111,  10: 11111,  11: 11111,  12: 11111,  13: 11111,  14: 11111,  15: 11111,  16: 11111,  17: 11111,  18: 11111,  19: 11111,  20: 11111,  21: 11111,  22: 11111,  23: 11111,  24: 22222,  25: 22222,  26: 22222,  27: 22222,  28: 22222,  29: 22222,  30: 22222,  31: 22222,  32: 22222,  33: 22222,  34: 22222,  35: 22222,  36: 22222,  37: 22222,  38: 22222,  39: 22222,  40: 22222,  41: 22222,  42: 22222,  43: 22222,  44: 22222,  45: 22222,  46: 22222,  47: 22222,  48: 22222,  49: 22222,  50: 22222,  51: 22222,  52: 22222,  53: 22222,  54: 22222,  55: 22222,  56: 22222,  57: 22222,  58: 22222,  59: 22222,  60: 33333,  61: 33333,  62: 33333,  63: 33333,  64: 33333,  65: 33333,  66: 33333,  67: 33333,  68: 33333,  69: 33333,  70: 33333,  71: 33333,  72: 33333,  73: 33333,  74: 33333,  75: 33333,  76: 33333,  77: 33333,  78: 33333,  79: 33333,  80: 33333,  81: 33333,  82: 33333,  83: 33333},
'month': {0: 1,  1: 2,  2: 3,  3: 4,  4: 5,  5: 6,  6: 7,  7: 8,  8: 9,  9: 10,  10: 11,  11: 12,  12: 1,  13: 2,  14: 3,  15: 4,  16: 5,  17: 6,  18: 7,  19: 8,  20: 9,  21: 10,  22: 11,  23: 12,  24: 1,  25: 2,  26: 3,  27: 4,  28: 5,  29: 6,  30: 7,  31: 8,  32: 9,  33: 10,  34: 11,  35: 12,  36: 1,  37: 2,  38: 3,  39: 4,  40: 5,  41: 6,  42: 7,  43: 8,  44: 9,  45: 10,  46: 11,  47: 12,  48: 1,  49: 2,  50: 3,  51: 4,  52: 5,  53: 6,  54: 7,  55: 8,  56: 9,  57: 10,  58: 11,  59: 12,  60: 1,  61: 2,  62: 3,  63: 4,  64: 5,  65: 6,  66: 7,  67: 8,  68: 9,  69: 10,  70: 11,  71: 12,  72: 1,  73: 2,  74: 3,  75: 4,  76: 5,  77: 6,  78: 7,  79: 8,  80: 9,  81: 10,  82: 11,  83: 12},
'x1': {0: 4.8399999999999999,  1: 1.4099999999999999,  2: 4.1299999999999999,  3: 3.1499999999999999,  4: -3.98,  5: -0.10000000000000001,  6: -4.5,  7: 3.79,  8: -0.84999999999999998,  9: -4.4199999999999999,  10: -0.46000000000000002,  11: 8.7100000000000009,  12: 2.4900000000000002,  13: 2.8700000000000001,  14: 0.63,  15: 0.28999999999999998,  16: 1.25,  17: -2.4300000000000002,  18: -0.80000000000000004,  19: 3.2599999999999998,  20: -1.1399999999999999,  21: 0.52000000000000002,  22: 4.5999999999999996,  23: 0.62,  24: 4.8399999999999999,  25: 1.4099999999999999,  26: 4.1299999999999999,  27: 3.1499999999999999,  28: -3.98,  29: -0.10000000000000001,  30: -4.5,  31: 3.79,  32: -0.84999999999999998,  33: -4.4199999999999999,  34: -0.46000000000000002,  35: 8.7100000000000009,  36: 2.4900000000000002,  37: 2.8700000000000001,  38: 0.63,  39: 0.28999999999999998,  40: 1.25,  41: -2.4300000000000002,  42: -0.80000000000000004,  43: 3.2599999999999998,  44: -1.1399999999999999,  45: 0.52000000000000002,  46: 4.5999999999999996,  47: 0.62,  48: -3.29,  49: -4.8499999999999996,  50: -1.29,  51: -5.6799999999999997,  52: -2.9399999999999999,  53: -1.5600000000000001,  54: 5.04,  55: -3.8399999999999999,  56: 4.75,  57: -0.85999999999999999,  58: -12.74,  59: 0.57999999999999996,  60: 5.5700000000000003,  61: 1.29,  62: 4.0300000000000002,  63: 1.55,  64: 2.7999999999999998,  65: -1.2,  66: 5.6500000000000004,  67: -2.71,  68: 3.77,  69: 4.1799999999999997,  70: 3.1200000000000001,  71: 2.8100000000000001,  72: -3.3199999999999998,  73: 4.6500000000000004,  74: 0.42999999999999999,  75: -0.19,  76: 2.0600000000000001,  77: 2.6099999999999999,  78: -2.04,  79: 4.2400000000000002,  80: -1.97,  81: 2.52,  82: 2.5499999999999998,  83: -0.059999999999999998},
'x2': {0: 7.4400000000000004,  1: 1.8999999999999999,  2: 2.5699999999999998,  3: -0.47999999999999998,  4: -1.1000000000000001,  5: -1.4299999999999999,  6: -1.5,  7: -0.19,  8: 0.40999999999999998,  9: -1.78,  10: -2.8300000000000001,  11: 3.2799999999999998,  12: 6.1100000000000003,  13: 1.3899999999999999,  14: -0.27000000000000002,  15: -0.02,  16: -2.79,  17: 0.32000000000000001,  18: -2.8900000000000001,  19: -4.0700000000000003,  20: -2.6899999999999999,  21: -2.71,  22: -1.1200000000000001,  23: -1.8600000000000001,  24: 7.4400000000000004,  25: 1.8999999999999999,  26: 2.5699999999999998,  27: -0.47999999999999998,  28: -1.1000000000000001,  29: -1.4299999999999999,  30: -1.5,  31: -0.19,  32: 0.40999999999999998,  33: -1.78,  34: -2.8300000000000001,  35: 3.2799999999999998,  36: 6.1100000000000003,  37: 1.3899999999999999,  38: -0.27000000000000002,  39: -0.02,  40: -2.79,  41: 0.32000000000000001,  42: -2.8900000000000001,  43: -4.0700000000000003,  44: -2.6899999999999999,  45: -2.71,  46: -1.1200000000000001,  47: -1.8600000000000001,  48: -3.5,  49: -3.9900000000000002,  50: -2.8700000000000001,  51: -3.9900000000000002,  52: -6.1200000000000001,  53: -2.9399999999999999,  54: 7.8600000000000003,  55: -2.04,  56: 2.9100000000000001,  57: -0.17000000000000001,  58: -7.7000000000000002,  59: -5.3300000000000001,  60: 0.44,  61: -0.42999999999999999,  62: 0.83999999999999997,  63: -2.4300000000000002,  64: 1.6899999999999999,  65: 1.1699999999999999,  66: 1.8799999999999999,  67: 0.25,  68: 2.9399999999999999,  69: -1.52,  70: 1.25,  71: -0.47999999999999998,  72: 0.87,  73: 0.34000000000000002,  74: -1.8500000000000001,  75: -4.1900000000000004,  76: -1.8500000000000001,  77: 3.0099999999999998,  78: -4.2199999999999998,  79: 0.40000000000000002,  80: -3.7999999999999998,  81: 4.2800000000000002,  82: -2.0499999999999998,  83: 2.5899999999999999},
'x3': {0: 1.3500000000000001,  1: -1.3400000000000001,  2: -4.0,  3: 0.73999999999999999,  4: -1.3799999999999999,  5: -2.0,  6: 0.14000000000000001,  7: 2.7200000000000002,  8: -2.9500000000000002,  9: -0.47999999999999998,  10: -1.75,  11: -0.23999999999999999,  12: 2.0600000000000001,  13: -2.75,  14: -1.6599999999999999,  15: 0.39000000000000001,  16: -2.73,  17: -2.4199999999999999,  18: 0.77000000000000002,  19: 4.6399999999999997,  20: 0.5,  21: 1.3200000000000001,  22: 4.7599999999999998,  23: -2.2599999999999998,  24: 1.3500000000000001,  25: -1.3400000000000001,  26: -4.0,  27: 0.73999999999999999,  28: -1.3799999999999999,  29: -2.0,  30: 0.14000000000000001,  31: 2.7200000000000002,  32: -2.9500000000000002,  33: -0.47999999999999998,  34: -1.75,  35: -0.23999999999999999,  36: 2.0600000000000001,  37: -2.75,  38: -1.6599999999999999,  39: 0.39000000000000001,  40: -2.73,  41: -2.4199999999999999,  42: 0.77000000000000002,  43: 4.6399999999999997,  44: 0.5,  45: 1.3200000000000001,  46: 4.7599999999999998,  47: -2.2599999999999998,  48: 2.7000000000000002,  49: 1.7,  50: 2.8300000000000001,  51: 5.6900000000000004,  52: 0.20999999999999999,  53: 1.4199999999999999,  54: -5.1799999999999997,  55: 1.1899999999999999,  56: 2.1099999999999999,  57: 1.74,  58: 4.0099999999999998,  59: 4.2400000000000002,  60: 0.94999999999999996,  61: 0.11,  62: -0.26000000000000001,  63: 0.56999999999999995,  64: 2.4900000000000002,  65: -0.13,  66: 0.60999999999999999,  67: -2.77,  68: -1.2,  69: 1.1000000000000001,  70: 0.26000000000000001,  71: -0.31,  72: -2.1299999999999999,  73: -0.37,  74: 5.0300000000000002,  75: 1.1000000000000001,  76: -0.35999999999999999,  77: -0.66000000000000003,  78: -0.02,  79: -0.55000000000000004,  80: -1.1899999999999999,  81: -1.6799999999999999,  82: -2.98,  83: 2.1200000000000001},
'y': {0: 37.543945819999998,  1: 8.9742475529999997,  2: -2.3528754309999997,  3: 13.13251636,  4: -1.60429428,  5: -11.956497779999999,  6: -19.876604879999999,  7: -2.325516618,  8: -4.7618724569999999,  9: 3.1666054689999998,  10: -1.625982086,  11: 23.14051619,  12: 36.241578869999998,  13: -4.0393970439999993,  14: -1.5464071159999999,  15: -5.8638777849999997,  16: 1.1173513309999998,  17: -7.7348398829999994,  18: 1.1975707259999999,  19: 8.1657380679999996,  20: 1.0988696200000001,  21: -4.8912916910000002,  22: 15.31432558,  23: -0.49755575099999999,  24: 2.439007991,  25: 3.7788248100000001,  26: 6.2406021170000008,  27: 0.070041193000000002,  28: -8.2320061649999996,  29: -3.0580604539999996,  30: -8.1230234560000003,  31: 4.824015073,  32: -0.082216824000000008,  33: -1.0699493369999999,  34: 2.0965058669999999,  35: 10.147223650000001,  36: 9.3610165409999997,  37: 0.50276726500000002,  38: 3.731305892,  39: 0.98107468400000009,  40: 3.3937931360000002,  41: -1.445663699,  42: 2.2321845640000002,  43: 2.2707284099999998,  44: -0.48955173399999996,  45: -5.1661444639999994,  46: 1.776962626,  47: 2.8132786730000001,  48: 8.3333586369999999,  49: -0.59700207599999999,  50: 0.0,  51: -5.4461723210000006,  52: -3.2260780789999997,  53: 0.71489267299999992,  54: -0.78864414099999991,  55: -3.936371727,  56: -14.285801190000001,  57: 8.6241378770000008,  58: -5.0419731539999999,  59: -6.8867527329999998,  60: 2.7716522460000004,  61: 2.1129326050000001,  62: 2.8956834530000002,  63: 15.714036009999999,  64: 6.1329305139999999,  65: -1.017191977,  66: -7.8303661889999994,  67: 5.6218592960000002,  68: -0.35928143700000004,  69: 6.385216346,  70: 8.4875017649999993,  71: -1.8882769469999998,  72: 1.1494252870000001,  73: 1.9820295980000002,  74: 6.9955625160000006,  75: -1.4393754569999999,  76: 2.0297029700000002,  77: 1.8563751830000002,  78: 3.5011990410000005,  79: 5.9082483779999997,  80: 2.0471054369999999,  81: 1.272648835,  82: 2.49201278,  83: -2.844593181},
'year': {0: 1971,  1: 1971,  2: 1971,  3: 1971,  4: 1971,  5: 1971,  6: 1971,  7: 1971,  8: 1971,  9: 1971,  10: 1971,  11: 1971,  12: 1972,  13: 1972,  14: 1972,  15: 1972,  16: 1972,  17: 1972,  18: 1972,  19: 1972,  20: 1972,  21: 1972,  22: 1972,  23: 1972,  24: 1971,  25: 1971,  26: 1971,  27: 1971,  28: 1971,  29: 1971,  30: 1971,  31: 1971,  32: 1971,  33: 1971,  34: 1971,  35: 1971,  36: 1972,  37: 1972,  38: 1972,  39: 1972,  40: 1972,  41: 1972,  42: 1972,  43: 1972,  44: 1972,  45: 1972,  46: 1972,  47: 1972,  48: 1973,  49: 1973,  50: 1973,  51: 1973,  52: 1973,  53: 1973,  54: 1973,  55: 1973,  56: 1973,  57: 1973,  58: 1973,  59: 1973,  60: 2013,  61: 2013,  62: 2013,  63: 2013,  64: 2013,  65: 2013,  66: 2013,  67: 2013,  68: 2013,  69: 2013,  70: 2013,  71: 2013,  72: 2014,  73: 2014,  74: 2014,  75: 2014,  76: 2014,  77: 2014,  78: 2014,  79: 2014,  80: 2014,  81: 2014,   82: 2014,    83: 2014}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pandas' `rolling` seems to have some limitations. First, it seems impossible to pass an entire frame of data via the `apply`. Instead, only values of a single column are passed. To get around this, we pass the index via the `apply` which allows to get the relevant data frame subset within the apply function itself.

Second, the returned value needs to be a float. This is of no use here because the [`sm.OLS.predict`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.predict.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.predict) returns an iterable of values. To fix this, we save the results in an extra container as a side effect and extract it later on.

```
def ols_predict(indices, result, ycol, xcols):
    roll_df = df.loc[indices] # get relevant data frame subset
    result[indices[-1]] = sm.OLS(roll_df[ycol], roll_df[xcols]).fit().predict()
    return 0 # value is irrelvant here

# define kwargs to be fet to the ols_predict
kwargs = {"xcols": ['constant','x1', 'x2', 'x3'], 
          "ycol": 'y', "result": {}}

# iterate id's sub data frames and call ols for rolling windows
df["identifier"] = df.index
for idx, sub_df in df.groupby("id"):
    sub_df["identifier"].rolling(12, min_periods=6).apply(ols_predict, kwargs=kwargs)

# write results back to original df
df["parameters"] = pd.Series(kwargs["result"])

# showing the last 5 computed values
print(df["parameters"].tail())

79    [2.71069564365, 3.86510820198, 3.65972798601, ...
80    [4.05363775104, 4.22653362401, 3.03918230523, ...
81    [3.55589161647, 2.49348201521, 1.20113347853, ...
82    [2.28561308212, 1.0537258681, 2.40806914305, 4...
83    [-0.428928897229, 3.22009689097, 3.30943586961...
Name: parameters, dtype: object
```

Overall, the workarounds are rather ugly using side effects. However, it accomplishes what you require. You can now modify your OLS function to whatever needed.

Comment: First, thank you. Second, is there a way to get the predicted value for `y` in each period without writing a function that does the calculation (e.g. for one observation: y_hat is the sum of the products of the parameters and their corresponding data). I'm thinking of something like the post-estimation command `model.y_predict` that I referenced above.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure about what you want to achieve here. You want to build a model containing 12 observations and then you want to predict the latest observation with the fitted model containing the last observation itself?

Comment: Yes. I suppose the term 'predict' isn't perfect here. I'm trying to separate  `'y'` into a portion explained by the model (what I'm calling the prediction) and a portion unexplained by the model (the residual).

Comment: So you mean something like [R squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)?

Comment: I'm not after a fit statistic, rather y* from equation (2) in [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18233/what-are-the-predicted-values-returned-by-the-predict-function-in-r-when-using). I'm trying to reproduce the [Stata  post-estimation command `predict`](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rpredict.pdf). Thanks for working with me on this!

Comment: I think see what is going on (now I understand my confusion). `df["parameters"]` is returning _all_ 12 (6 to 12) predictions for each observation that was used to calculate the model for that month. I think I just need to keep the last element of each cell in `df["parameters"]`. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to have helped you. You can modify your `ols_predict` function to whatever statistic you need.

Comment: I get KerError: -1 when I try to run this now, relating to this line: `result[indices[-1]] = sm.OLS(roll_df[ycol], roll_df[xcols]).fit().predict()`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Vash What pandas version are you using?

Comment: @pansen I'm on Pandas 1.0.1.; Python 3.8.1.